# How to start CCBFile animation on call in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I ceated the CCBFile in Sprite Builder and added in a main scene, now when i run the project that CCBFile animation start automatically. I want to start or call it after some delay... any idea?

here is my code...

```
@implementation MainScene {
CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
CCNode *playerbackwardshort;

}

// is called when CCB file has completed loading
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {

//For Delay
[self performSelector:@selector(Upgrade)  withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
}


-(void)Upgrade{
CCBAnimationManager* am = self.userObject;
[am runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"playerbackwardshort"];
}
```

Comment: show the relevant code, please...

Comment: @sergio you can read my code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CCBAnimationManager` is used for this. Let's say that you named your animation 'AnimationTest`. To stop it from running automatically, there's an option for it in the timeline properties ([see here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mgwu-misc/Spritebuilder+Tutorial/Spritebuilder_BlinkJump.png))

```
// in the loaded ccb file's class
CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;
[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"AnimationTest"];
```

Comment: The program stops on this line

[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"backwardshort"];

Comment: Would you care to investigate the problem? Why does it stop, at what line of the function call does it stop?

Comment: lets start it step by step

1. created new sprite file in sprite builder.
2. Set no. of pictures for animation.
3. add that sprite to the main scene.
4. Assign a variable "_playerbackwardshort" to that ccbFile.
5. Now open Xcode.
6. in implementation (CCNode *_playerbackwardshort;)
7. in - (void)didLoadFromCCB  method add these two line you posted with replacement of animationTest to _playerbackwardshort.

Comment: Is your animation timeline named `_playerbackwardshort `? Because if it isn't, animation manager would not be able to load it.

Comment: i assign it "Doc Root Var" with name "_playerbackwardshort", can u please guide me step by step... i tried many methods like custom class of that animation with name "player" added it in AppDelegate "[CCBReader load:@"Player"];" then added your line but it gives error "Warning: File not found: Player.ccbi"

so please guide me step by step with any of your example in which you manage your sprite builder animation in xcode. Thanks

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/sprite-animation-spritebuilder/), read the 'Unsynchronize the animations' section.